# Finding a constant without integration of joint pdf

Tags: integration, density-function, multiple-integral

I have a joint pdf:

$c\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2},  x^2 + y^2 \le 1$

I need to find c and I know this can be done by doing the double integration over the possible of values of y and x and equating the result to 1. However, that seems a tedious approach involving trigonometric substitutions. Hence, I'm looking for other suggestions/ approaches to find the constant. Any suggestions?

Comment: polar coordinates?

Comment: Hi @AnginaSeng, could you please elaborate?

Comment: The integral of $\sqrt {1 - x^2 - y^2}$ over the unit disk is the volume of a half-ball of radius $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing in polar coordinates you have only to integrate over the unit disk with radius $\leq1$ and angle $\theta$, say $x^2+y^2=\rho^2$ with jacobian =$\rho$ you get immediately

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta \int_{0}^{1} \rho\sqrt{1-\rho^2} d\rho=\frac{2}{3}\pi$$

the first integral is $2\pi$ while the second is immediate when you set $1-\rho^2=u$

your constant is the reciprocal of this quantity

Summary to use polar coordinates:

the problem is to integrate the function in the domain $x^2+y^2<1$. This domain is the entire unit disk, say a disk with radius 1 and $\theta \in (0;2\pi)$. To pass in polar coordinates you have to make the following substitution;

$$
\begin{cases}
x=\rho cos\theta \\
y=\rho sin\theta
\end{cases}$$

It is very easy to calculate the jacobian writing the matrix of the partial derivatives that gives $|J|=\rho$

$$det \begin{bmatrix}
    cos\theta &-\rho sin\theta \\
   sin\theta &\rho cos\theta \\
    \end{bmatrix}=\rho(\underbrace{cos^2\theta+sin^2\theta}_{=1})=\rho$$

so, observing that $x^2+y^2=\rho^2$ you integral becomes

$$\underbrace{\int_{0}^{2\pi}d \theta}_{\text{angle from 0 to $2\pi$}}\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\rho\sqrt{1-\rho^2} d\rho}_{\text{radius $0<\rho<1$}}$$

Comment: Thanks! But may I know how did you arrive at this double integral?

Comment: @statstudent :look at the edit in my answer

Comment: Thanks so much! Can I clarify a couple of things? 
1) Does the double integral that you wrote give the area of a section of the unit disk?
2) What were the two equations that you specified to find the Jacobian?

Comment: @statstudent : are you familiar with polar coordinates change of variables?

Comment: Yes, I just learnt it actually. As I understand it, you need two functions U = g_1(X,Y) and V = g_2(X,Y) which have continuous partial derivatives, and there should exist functions X = h_1(U,V) and Y = h_2(U,V). Then you can express the joint density of U,V in terms of the original density by substituting in the functions h_1 and h_2 and the absolute value of the inverse of the Jacobian. What I can't see here are the functions g_1 and g_2.

Comment: @statstudent : perhaps you have to sudy again how this important transformatio works...I edited my answer with a brief summary but I do not know if it is enough to make you familiar with this issue

Comment: Thanks so much for the extended explanation! I've looked through a textbook on the conversion to polar integrals and I understand your answer better now!